# CSS issue: Applying a class to a slider image tag to change the background color

Tags: css, image, background, tags

A colleague and I have been stumped on a CSS issue for a few hours now and we don't seem to know exactly why it's happening.

If you look at http://www.currysauto.com/services/brakes/brake-job-rear-disc.aspx, the thumbnail images are picking up on a css rule called .ndcustomcolorclass which turns the images where there's alpha blue. However, with the same rule applied to the big images, it doesn't seem to be working. However, being more specific does change the image blue (say you were to use .nivoSlider img, this would make the image blue). My question is, why isn't the big image picking up on the rule to change the background color like the thumbnails are.

Thank you.

Comment: Seems to work fine if I add a background-color to #slider img, the big images get the color. I think I misunderstand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like the slider plugin is "playing" visual tricks on you. The images inside the `a` elements are not the ones that are seen (you can tell because they have `visibility: hidden`). The plugin is using another `img` tag for the main image and that is a little further down (`<img class="nivo-main-image">`). THAT is the image that you need to apply your `ndcustomcolorclass` class on. The trouble is that image is generated dynamically so you probably can't just add a class on it to begin with. I can see at least 2 options:

- add the class through jquery:

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("img.nivo-main-image").addClass("ndcustomcolorclass");
  });
  ```
- hack the CSS directly:

  ```css
  .nivo-main-image {background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #003D7D;}
  ```